# What is the relationship between division and proving an integer is odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to use proof by contradiction to prove:

$101$ is an odd integer.

I know that the first step is to assume that $101$ is even, so:

$101 = 2q, q \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then I am stuck. I don't know how to use the above statement to create a contraction.

The given solution is:

> We get a contradiction if we remember how we did divison in our early school-days. Then we would have divided $2$ into $101$ giving $50$ with remainder $1$. This suggests
>   $$101 = 2q \Rightarrow 1 = 101 - 100 = 2q - 2\times 50 = 2(q - 50) \ge 2 \Rightarrow 1 \ge 2$$
>   and we have a contradiction since it is certainly true that $1 < 2$.

According to the solution, the key is to realise that $2$ divides $101$ with a remainder of $1$.

My problem is that even if I did realise the above, it still would not have occurred to me to write $1 = 101 -100$ i.e. the next step of the proof by contradiction.

What is the connection between realising that $2$ divides $101 $with remainder $1$ and writing $1=101-100$ and what are the thought processes that made you realise it?

EDIT:

The solution above was just the workings. The formal proof that the solution provide is:

> Suppose for contradiction that $101$ is even so that $101=2q$ for some integer $q$. Then $1=2(q-50)$ where $q-50$ must be a positive integer. But $2(q-50)\geq 2$ so that $1\geq 2$ contradicting the fact that $1 \lt 2$. Hence 101 is not even and so must be odd.

Comment: [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), i.e. division with remainder: $101 = 50\times 2 + 1 \Longrightarrow 101 - 100 = 1$.

Comment: The "mental process" is in the hint : "remember how we did division ... we would have divide 101 by 2 giving 50 and reminder 1". I.e. $101 = 2 \times 50 + 1$; thus (with elementary algebra) : $1 = 101 - 2 \times 50$.

Comment: I disagree with the given solution: nothing justifies $2(q-50)\ge 2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - you are right ... The argument in the above "hint" is sloppy. From the assumption that $101=2 \times q, q \in \mathbb Z^+$ we have that $1=2(q- 50)$. This it is enough to conclude, because we have **no** positive integer which satisfy it.